# Problem loading github and some more pages

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, network-manager

I've read many posts that talk about similar problems but anything has worked for me.
When I try to enter github.com it says:

> No se puede conectar
>
> Firefox no puede establecer una conexión con el servidor en github.com.

I've tried with other browsers and happens the same. (now I'm using Firefox Quantum).
I've done host with github:

```
$ host www.github.com

www.github.com is an alias for github.com.
github.com has address 192.30.253.113
github.com has address 192.30.253.112
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

and:

**ping -c 3 www.github.com**

```
PING github.com (192.30.253.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.254.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

and:
**traceroute www.github.com**

```
traceroute to www.github.com (192.30.253.113), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.254.100 (192.168.254.100)  3061.719 ms !H  3061.680 ms !H  3061.672 ms !H
```

but with google everything is fine:

```
$ traceroute www.google.es
traceroute to www.google.es (216.58.210.163), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.649 ms  1.042 ms  1.770 ms
 2  static-10-0-235-87.ipcom.comunitel.net (87.235.0.10)  20.051 ms  22.691 ms  24.117 ms
 3  172.29.144.110 (172.29.144.110)  25.077 ms 172.29.144.106 (172.29.144.106)  27.848 ms 172.29.144.110 (172.29.144.110)  28.457 ms
```

Thank you

**ip route show**:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0f1  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0f1  proto static  scope link  metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.0.0.0/8 dev vboxnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.254.100 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.161  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.156  metric 600
```

Comment: And what is the issue here?

Comment: That I can't connect to github or other pages like [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=175783)

Comment: What is your interface's netmask? please [edit] your question to include the output of `ip route show`

Comment: Your issue is likely related to the routing table entry `192.0.0.0/8 dev vboxnet0` - did you add that manually? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is from VirtualBox and I just created it inside VirtualBox but not manually.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I think I found the solution to my problem. After [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) said [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977722/problem-loading-github-and-some-more-pages?noredirect=1#comment1569829_977722), I thought why not update the virtualbox, because it seemed to be something related to it. And I did it and everything works fine!

The version of the VirtualBox I am using now is 5.2.0.